# For loop can not find the next raster object in the geodatabase. OSError: "" does not exist

Tags: arcpy, python, raster

I'm trying to convert a list of rasters in a geodatabase to integer type and rename them with a specific folder name as the prefix. This first block of code moves the ASCII rasters into the geodatabase. And it works fine.

```
import arcpy, os
from arcpy import env
from arcpy.sa import *

# Set the environment variables
sr = arcpy.SpatialReference(26911)
env.overwriteOutput=True
env.extent = 'MAXOF'


### Change to the desired scenario/replicate
# "Scenario1_Rep2"
# "Scenario1_Rep6"
# "Scenario2_Rep2"
# "Scenario2_Rep5"
# "Scenario3_Rep2"
# "Scenario3_Rep7"
# "Scenario4_Rep2"
# "Scenario4_Rep9"

# set workspace
scene = "Scenario1_Rep2"
path = "C:\\GIS\\PROJECT\\LakeTahoeWest\\Data\\LANDIS\\WaterQualityAnalysis\\"
env.workspace = os.path.join(path, scene)

# define output gdb
outgdb = "C:\\GIS\\PROJECT\\LakeTahoeWest\\Data\\LANDIS\\WaterQualityAnalysis\\WaterQualityAnalysis.gdb"

# Get a list of rasters from the workspace
rasters = arcpy.ListRasters("*", "ALL")

# loop through raster list 
for raster in rasters:
    # create describe object of each raster
    desc = arcpy.Describe(raster)
    inras = desc.CatalogPath
    print ("Copied " + desc.baseName + " to fgdb.")
    # create new raster in gdb
    arcpy.RasterToGeodatabase_conversion(inras, outgdb)
```

This next block of code is where the error happens:

```
import arcpy, os

# Name = "WaterQualityAnalysis"
# wFolder = r"C:\GIS\PROJECT\LakeTahoeWest\Data\LANDIS\WaterQualityAnalysis"
# GDB = os.path.join(str(Name) + ".gdb")

# env.workspace = os.path.join(str(wFolder), str(GDB))
# print (arcpy.Exists(env.workspace))

env.workspace ="C:\\GIS\\PROJECT\\LakeTahoeWest\\Data\\LANDIS\\WaterQualityAnalysis\\WaterQualityAnalysis.gdb"

# Get a list of rasters from the workspace
rasters = arcpy.ListRasters("*_img", "ALL")
print(rasters)
# loop through raster list 
for raster in rasters:

    # create describe object of each raster
    desc = arcpy.Describe(raster)
    inras = desc.CatalogPath
    print(inras)
    # project the raster to UTM Zone 11N
    arcpy.DefineProjection_management(inras, sr)
    # get the new name to print
    dsc = arcpy.Describe(inras)
    year = str(dsc.baseName[0:-4].split('_')[-1])
    event = str(dsc.baseName[0:-4].split('_')[0])

    print ("Created: " + dsc.baseName)

    # convert to integer type and save to gdb
    outras = Int(inras)
    outras.save(outgdb + "\\" + scene + "_" + event + "_" + year)
    # return success message
    desc = arcpy.Describe(outras)
    print ("Created: "+ desc.baseName)
    print ("Deleting " + dsc.baseName)
    arcpy.Delete_management(inras)
```

As you can see, I've messed around with the path names a bit thinking that was the issue.

Here is the output and error I'm getting:

```
['fire_intensity_41_img', 'fire_intensity_42_img', 'fire_intensity_43_img', 'fire_intensity_44_img', 'fire_intensity_45_img', 'fire_intensity_46_img', 'fire_intensity_47_img', 'fire_intensity_48_img', 'fire_intensity_49_img', 'fire_intensity_50_img']
C:\GIS\PROJECT\LakeTahoeWest\Data\LANDIS\WaterQualityAnalysis\WaterQualityAnalysis.gdb\fire_intensity_41_img
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
OSError                                   Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-14-44c2fe5a12b6> in <module>
     17 
     18     # create describe object of each raster
---> 19     desc = arcpy.Describe(raster)
     20     inras = desc.CatalogPath
     21     print(inras)

C:\Program Files\ArcGIS\Pro\Resources\ArcPy\arcpy\__init__.py in Describe(value, data_type)
   1241        class with the same name. In this case, the data type is used to clarify
   1242        which dataset you want to describe."""
-> 1243     return gp.describe(value, data_type)
   1244 
   1245 def CreateObject(name, options=None):

C:\Program Files\ArcGIS\Pro\Resources\ArcPy\arcpy\geoprocessing\_base.py in describe(self, *args)
    366         from arcpy.arcobjects.arcobjectconversion import convertArcObjectToPythonObject
    367         return convertArcObjectToPythonObject(
--> 368                     self._gp.Describe(*gp_fixargs(args, True)))
    369     def createObject(self, *args):
    370         """GP function CreateObject"""

OSError: "fire_intensity_42_img" does not exist
```

Comment: Have you tried inspecting "fire_intensity_42_img" in your FGDB to make sure it is not corrupt?

Comment: Yeah it's a legit raster. I pulled it into ArcMap and was able to do other geoprocessing tasks on it.

Comment: All of the rasters are showing up in the list generated by arcpy.ListRasters().

Comment: How are you implementing the script? Any difference running the script using an IDE vs the ArcGIS interpreter?

Comment: I've been running it in a Jupyter Notebook against my ArcPro environment. I'll try it as a script in IDLE. I think this might be the issue....Great catch. I'll report back in bit.

Comment: The script works using IDLE and my Python 2.7 environment! I guess something is messed up with my ArcPro Python 3 environment. I'll take that issue up with ESRI tech support. How do I mark your answer as correct?

Comment: Glad we were able to troubleshoot that—I have included an answer based on the comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mentioned in the comments that you are implementing the script using Jupyter. The issue is likely related to a bad or broken call to your arcpy site package. You can test this by running the script first on Jupyter and then on the ArcGIS Python interpreter.

Comment: Thanks for the help. This problem is indeed an issue with the arcpy site package run in a Jupyter notebook. I've opened a ticket with ESRI Tech support. I'll post their answer here.